# Can't save PdfPage as a BitmapImage to disk

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm trying to save the pages of a `PdfDocument` into the disk as a set of `BitmapImage`'s, for which I'm using the extensions provided by WinRTXamlToolkit.

```
PdfPage page = pdfd.GetPage(0); // pdfd is a loaded PdfDocument
InMemoryRandomAccessStream str=new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await page.RenderToStreamAsync(str);
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
await bmp.SetSourceAsync(str);

WriteableBitmap wb = await WriteableBitmapFromBitmapImageExtension.FromBitmapImage(bmp);

StorageFolder sfo;
sfo = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("PDFasBMP", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

await WriteableBitmapSaveExtensions.SaveToFile(wb,sfo,"Yahooo.bmp");
```

The output "Yahooo.bmp" is an unreadable 58-bytes file.  What am I missing ? The problem has nothing to do with the WinRTXamlToolkit as when the `BitmapImage` is set to an image in the web it is saved to the disk properly, so the problem is with how the PdfPage works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the BitmapImage and load your PDF directly into the WriteableBitmap:

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(1,1);
await wb.SetSourceAsync(str);
```

It's not possible to extract the pixels from a BitmapImage, so WriteableBitmapFromBitmapImageExtension.FromBitmapImage has has to get the data from elsewhere: it works when the BitmapImage is loaded from the web since FromBitmapImage can get the BitmapImage's UriSource and load that URI into the WriteableBitmap.

Comment: The compiler says that `WriteableBitmap` does't have a constructor that takes 0 arguments. Looks like it needs the pixelWidth and pixelHeight to be specified when being made, which is not known.

Comment: You can create it with any size. The SetSourceAsync will reset the size to match the source stream.